# Setting UTC as default date timezone

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have installed and configured TypeORM successfully; I can add new records, search, etc. I'm trying to set default timezone to `UTC` for 4 hours... but without success

I have set node TZ config to `UTC` and when I print `console.log(process.env.TZ)` it returns `UTC` as expected.

am I doing something wrong? My "User" Entity code:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Unique, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, BaseEntity} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
//@Unique(['email'])
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  email!: string;

  @Column()
  password!: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({name: 'created_at', type: 'timestamp'})
  createdAt!: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({name: 'updated_at',type: 'timestamp'})
  updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

And connection config:

```
{
  name: 'default',
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'supersecret',
  database: 'multichat',
  timezone: 'Z',
  syncronize: true,
  logging: false,
  entities: [
    '/var/www/html/projects/sluy/multichat/api_express/src/database/entities/**/*.ts'
  ],
  migrations: [
    '/var/www/html/projects/sluy/multichat/api_express/src/database/migrations/**/*.ts'
  ],
  subscribers: [
    '/var/www/html/projects/sluy/multichat/api_express/src/database/subscribers/**/*.ts'
  ],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: '/var/www/html/projects/sluy/multichat/api_express/src/database/entities',
    migrationsDir: '/var/www/html/projects/sluy/multichat/api_express/src/database/migrations',
    subscribersDir: '/var/www/html/projects/sluy/multichat/api_express/src/database/subscribers'
  }
}
```

Comment: typeorm connection properties [doc](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/connection-options.md)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that TypeORM's connection option `timezone` isn't working properly with mysql:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5895.

What is probably happening is that your connection is getting the timezone info from the system. You can verify this with `SELECT @@session.time_zone;`.

##### Solution

What worked for me was setting the timezone info manually upon starting the server:

```js
await manager.query(`SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';`)
await manager.query(`SET time_zone = '+00:00';`)
```